# Nested loops to write to 2d array

Tags: excel, vba

I'm pretty new to VBA, but I'm trying to automate a task at work by extracting values from one workbook to then populate another, but I've hit a snag early on. I thought it would be a good idea to use nested loops to populate a 2d array, but although the code "runs" it doesn't give me the result I need.

Here's the section that's troubling me so far:

```
Dim AccArray(63, 2) As Variant
Dim MonArray(1 To 12) As String
MonArray(1) = "apr"
MonArray(2) = "may"
MonArray(3) = "jun"
MonArray(4) = "jul"
MonArray(5) = "aug"
MonArray(6) = "sep"
MonArray(7) = "oct"
MonArray(8) = "nov"
MonArray(9) = "dec"
MonArray(10) = "jan"
MonArray(11) = "feb"
MonArray(12) = "mar"

Dim TxYrArray(1 To 5) As String
TxYrArray(1) = "4"
TxYrArray(2) = "3"
TxYrArray(3) = "2"
TxYrArray(4) = "1"
TxYrArray(5) = ""

For i = 1 To 64
    For t = 1 To 5
        For m = 1 To 12
            For j = 1 To 3
                Dim search As String
                search = "cy" & TxYrArray(t) & "_" & MonArray(m) & "_transaction_value"
                Set x = Cells.Find(what:=search, After:=Cells(1, 1) _
                , LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
                AccArray(i - 1, j - 1) = x.Offset(, j).Value
Next: Next: Next: Next
'Permutations tried so far
't i j m
'm t i j
'j i m t
'j i t m
'j t i m
'j t m i
'j m i t
'j m t i
'i m t j
'i m j t
'i j m t
'i j t m
'i t j m
'i t m j
```

At first I thought I might be the order of the loops, so I tried a number of permutations but to no avail. I've been trying for about 20 minutes to find a way to include tables so I can show you what I want the array to look like, and subsequently show you what it does instead, but it seems tables and stackoverflow don't mesh well, so I'll try and explain.

I want it to find "cy_apr_transaction_value", then write to AccArray(0,0), then find "cy_may_transaction_value" and write to AccArray((1,0), and so on until "mar", then do "cy1_apr_transaction_value". After cy4_mar, I want it to switch to the next column and start again at cy_apr.

What it instead seems to be doing is that every value in each column is the value of the last entry of the column, so it's the value of the "cy4_mar" for everything in that column.

One thing I just realised might be the issue is that in the array there are 4 rows which separate the 4 years, I just figured I would clear their contents after pasting the array, as I don't know how to work around thoes pesky rows without creating an array for each year (5 total), and I'd like to minimise the # of lines where possible.

Can anyone help me, or have I gone the wrong way about this?

**Edit:** 
Some screencaps to illustrate the problem

[image: An example of the source sheet, ignore the actual values.]

[image: On the left is the desired outcome, but the current outcome is on the right. The array is the bordered area, a smaller version of my desired array in the code.]

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59759919/edit) to show us screen caps of your source and destination sheets (i.e. expected result)? (you can upload images to http://imgur.com and link to them here)

Comment: I agree, this really needs sample data and expected results.

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/152388) to me.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I've added some screen caps, hope that helps.